# How does the .split() function work in java?

Tags: java

I've been trying to make this code block to work:

```
System.out.println("Please type a sentence.");
String input = scan.nextLine();

for (String u: input.split(" ")) {          
System.out.println(u);      
}
```

The code seems to work in the sense that I want a different word for each line, and I need to use the .split() function, but I don't know WHY it's working.

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear on what you're asking. The `split` method returns an array, and you're iterating over that array. Is that sort of what you're looking for?

Comment: `split()` splits the input on each occurrence of the character you chose and puts the different tokens in an array. Then you iterate over the array and print each token on a new line.

Comment: Before asking questions, I'd recommend you look at the official documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: I think you need to put [] ie String[] u=input.split(""). After you use split(" "), it assigns value such as u[1]=Please,u[2]=Type,u[3]=a,u[4]=sentence. It will assign the values like this.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct (and often most appropriate) way of understanding how a particular method is working is by referring to its API documentation and further to its implementation.

The API for `String.split()` can be found e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

And since the Java libraries are open source you can see their implementation at any time.

To do so you can, for instance, simply place a break point at the line where you have a call to `String.split()` and then step into it.

(which requires your classpath and libraries to be set correctly).

Alternatively, you can simply open the corresponding .java file from the src.zip archive located at your JDK's installation root.

The implementation of most of these basic methods is very lean and small so you should not have a hard time studying it.

To answer your question appropriately please find the exact implementation plus its documentation as defined within Oracles `String` class String.java:

---

```
/**
 * Splits this string around matches of the given
 * <a href="../util/regex/Pattern.html#sum">regular expression</a>.
 *
 * <p> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this
 * string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given
 * expression or is terminated by the end of the string.  The substrings in
 * the array are in the order in which they occur in this string.  If the
 * expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array
 * has just one element, namely this string.
 *
 * <p> When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this
 * string then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning
 * of the resulting array. A zero-width match at the beginning however
 * never produces such empty leading substring.
 *
 * <p> The {@code limit} parameter controls the number of times the
 * pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting
 * array.  If the limit <i>n</i> is greater than zero then the pattern
 * will be applied at most <i>n</i>&nbsp;-&nbsp;1 times, the array's
 * length will be no greater than <i>n</i>, and the array's last entry
 * will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.  If <i>n</i>
 * is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
 * possible and the array can have any length.  If <i>n</i> is zero then
 * the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can
 * have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.
 *
 * <p> The string {@code "boo:and:foo"}, for example, yields the
 * following results with these parameters:
 *
 * <blockquote><table cellpadding=1 cellspacing=0 summary="Split example showing regex, limit, and result">
 * <tr>
 *     <th>Regex</th>
 *     <th>Limit</th>
 *     <th>Result</th>
 * </tr>
 * <tr><td align=center>:</td>
 *     <td align=center>2</td>
 *     <td>{@code { "boo", "and:foo" }}</td></tr>
 * <tr><td align=center>:</td>
 *     <td align=center>5</td>
 *     <td>{@code { "boo", "and", "foo" }}</td></tr>
 * <tr><td align=center>:</td>
 *     <td align=center>-2</td>
 *     <td>{@code { "boo", "and", "foo" }}</td></tr>
 * <tr><td align=center>o</td>
 *     <td align=center>5</td>
 *     <td>{@code { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }}</td></tr>
 * <tr><td align=center>o</td>
 *     <td align=center>-2</td>
 *     <td>{@code { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }}</td></tr>
 * <tr><td align=center>o</td>
 *     <td align=center>0</td>
 *     <td>{@code { "b", "", ":and:f" }}</td></tr>
 * </table></blockquote>
 *
 * <p> An invocation of this method of the form
 * <i>str.</i>{@code split(}<i>regex</i>{@code ,}&nbsp;<i>n</i>{@code )}
 * yields the same result as the expression
 *
 * <blockquote>
 * <code>
 * {@link java.util.regex.Pattern}.{@link
 * java.util.regex.Pattern#compile compile}(<i>regex</i>).{@link
 * java.util.regex.Pattern#split(java.lang.CharSequence,int) split}(<i>str</i>,&nbsp;<i>n</i>)
 * </code>
 * </blockquote>
 *
 *
 * @param  regex
 *         the delimiting regular expression
 *
 * @param  limit
 *         the result threshold, as described above
 *
 * @return  the array of strings computed by splitting this string
 *          around matches of the given regular expression
 *
 * @throws  PatternSyntaxException
 *          if the regular expression's syntax is invalid
 *
 * @see java.util.regex.Pattern
 *
 * @since 1.4
 * @spec JSR-51
 */
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    /* fastpath if the regex is a
     (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
        RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
     (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
        the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
     */
    char ch = 0;
    if (((regex.value.length == 1 &&
         ".$|()[{^?*+\\".indexOf(ch = regex.charAt(0)) == -1) ||
         (regex.length() == 2 &&
          regex.charAt(0) == '\\' &&
          (((ch = regex.charAt(1))-'0')|('9'-ch)) < 0 &&
          ((ch-'a')|('z'-ch)) < 0 &&
          ((ch-'A')|('Z'-ch)) < 0)) &&
        (ch < Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE ||
         ch > Character.MAX_LOW_SURROGATE))
    {
        int off = 0;
        int next = 0;
        boolean limited = limit > 0;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((next = indexOf(ch, off)) != -1) {
            if (!limited || list.size() < limit - 1) {
                list.add(substring(off, next));
                off = next + 1;
            } else {    // last one
                //assert (list.size() == limit - 1);
                list.add(substring(off, value.length));
                off = value.length;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If no match was found, return this
        if (off == 0)
            return new String[]{this};

        // Add remaining segment
        if (!limited || list.size() < limit)
            list.add(substring(off, value.length));

        // Construct result
        int resultSize = list.size();
        if (limit == 0) {
            while (resultSize > 0 && list.get(resultSize - 1).length() == 0) {
                resultSize--;
            }
        }
        String[] result = new String[resultSize];
        return list.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
    }
    return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split` method works using the regex you give it and splitting the implicit argument wherever that expression occurs.

For example:

```
"qwerty uiop asdfghjkl".split(" ");
       ^    ^
```

The string will be broken up at these points because we specified that we wanted to split at a space, producing the following String array:

```
{"qwerty", "uiop", "asdfghjkl"}
```